# How to update a kivy ListProperty of root widget from a child widget?

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following kivy layout in my app

```
ABC:

<ABC>:

    BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: str(root.current_cell)

    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 10
```

The contents of the grid layout is dynamically generated in the Python code

```
class ABC(BoxLayout):
    current_cell = ListProperty([0, 0])
    
    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.draw_grid()

    def draw_grid(self):
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                self.ids.grid.add_widget(Cell(cell_id=[i, j]))
```

Cell widget is a child of TextInput widget

```
class Cell(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, cell_id, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cell_id = cell_id

    def _on_focus(self, instance, value, *largs):
        if value:
            ABC.current_cell = self.cell_id # Issue is here
        return super()._on_focus(instance, value, *largs)
```

When the user focuses any cell in the grid it should update the `ABC.current_cell` which in turn will update the label's text in the layout. The above code is not working. I am new to kivy so having hard time understanding what is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you should change the `root` (here in your example, `App`) widget's name to avoid any unexpected naming clashes. Secondly, try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Yeah. This code is just an example. The actual class name is different in my code. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to pass a reference from the ABC class to the Cell class and modify it later.

Small example:

```
class ABC(BoxLayout):
    current_cell = ListProperty([0, 0])
    def draw_grid(self):
        add = self.ids.grid.add_widget             
        add(Cell(abc=self, cell_id=[i, j]))

class Cell(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, abc, cell_id):
        self.abc = abc
        self.cell_id = cell_id

    def _on_focus(self):
        self.abc.current_cell = self.cell_id
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried passing the reference to the `current_cell` to Cell class but passing the reference to the root widget was the way to go!